# Subquery or Join a table where a certain value is minimum

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that has an ID in it, that is reference in multiple rows in a second table. I need to join both tables, but only select the columns from the second table where a certain column is MIN. Caveat to this is I also need to select other columns from tableb, and not just the minimum value. I need to reference the other columns that are relative to that minimum value.

Psuedo code due to code and data being confidential.

```
SELECT tablea.id, tableb.id, tableb.name FROM tablea
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * FROM tableb WHERE `id` = Minimum )
```

Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Some sample data (for both tables), and wanted result, please!

Comment: Will add some sample data asap.

Comment: Minimum is not a string, I need to select the entire table where a value is the minimum so WHERE tableb.id = MIN[id]. The minimum value would be a dollar figure for each ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this...

```
SELECT tablea.id, tableb.id, tableb.name 
FROM tablea a, tableb b
WHERE a.id = b.id AND b.amt =  (SELECT MIN(z.amt) FROM tableb z 
                                       WHERE z.id = a.id )
```

Comment: This looks sound, having issues implementing it via Tableau though. I'm having issues in the subquery referencing the alias for tablea.

Comment: I got it to work like this
`code
SELECT tablea.id, tableb.id, tableb.name 
FROM tablea a
LEFT JOIN tableb b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.id = b.id AND b.amt =  (SELECT MIN(z.amt) FROM tableb z 
                                       WHERE z.id = a.id )
`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.id, b.id, b.name 
FROM tablea a
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT *, row_number() over(partition by id order by dollar_amt_column) as rn 
           FROM tableb ) b
on a.id = b.id and b.rn = 1
```

Assuming you need the `minimum` value of `id` column, you could use `row_number` and `join` it to the other table.

Comment: Is this Microsoft Server SQL compatible?

Comment: yes it is..but you might have to include a `partition by` clause as well..which i can include if i see some sample data\